# Is it bad to group together like tests into a single test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

My team is using Cucumber / Ruby on Rails. We have some scenarios such as the following:

```
Scenario: Create a Data Set
Scenario: Update a Data Set
Scenario: Invalid Data Set - Invalid Name
Scenario: Invalid Data Set - Missing Source
Scenario: Invalid Data Set - Invalid Rate
...
```

A co-worker is asking that I group together all of the invalid tests into a single scenario. His reasoning is because when we sit with our Quality team, we have to read all of the scenarios aloud, and it would save time by only reading one instead of many.

```
Scenario: Create a Data Set
Scenario: Update a Data Set
Scenario: Invalid Data Set
  # Steps for invalid name
  # Steps for missing source
  # Steps for invalid rate
```

I don't think I can agree with this because I feel that tests should be completely isolated. If I want to add a new invalid scenario, then I would have to run more code than I need to if they were grouped together. I wanted to know if anyone had a more official answer.

Is it bad to group together like tests into a single test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general lumping tests together is a bad thing - skipping the setup/teardown phases in between assertions can lead to ordering issues where a previous test causes a test to fail/pass.

However if you are simply testing that a record should not be valid and that the user should get feedback about the errors in full it does actually make sense have have multiple assertions in a single scenario. Especially since it may be significantly faster since you are not running a full request cycle for each.

```
Scenario: Creating a thing with invalid data
  When I create a thing without filling in the required fields
  Then I should see "Invalid Name"
  Then I should see "Missing Source"
  Then I should see "Invalid Rate"
```

Answer (score 3):

I also believe in isolation of tests but I think you've found a case where some deeper thought leads me to think that lumping those specific assertions together in a single test is fine. My rule of thumb tends to revolve around separation of concerns. This doesn't mean treat those as separate concerns, but rather that testing invalid feedback is a single concern.

There are gotchas to this, of course. If you accept that separation as Law, you can find yourself putting tons of assertions in the same test and that's not good either.

Another is the performance concern that @max mentions in his answer (which is a good one).

Finally, you might find that not separating those tests makes it impossible to test them all together. Failure of the first test may keep any further failures from being revealed. In cucumber this is less of an issue because you're checking visual output, not performing assertions on code failures.

For your specific example, testing invalid conditions in a test seems pretty group-able.

Bottom line: your head is in the right place and you just need to keep in mind that there are very few hard and fast rules in the world that must NEVER be broken.